# pgadmin4 binary path file not found

Tags: pgadmin-4

I have a problem of binary path on python version for arch linux, the error occurred when I was trying to make a backup, I don't know what the pgadmin4 path is like, I am using manjaro.

I try to find the route, but I don't know if it's in the venv or where

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.